# Listview is too slow when loading

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

I am populating a list view with 1286 records, it takes about 34 seconds. i searched in internet and found this

```
 private void PopulateListViewWithCables(List<Cable> cables)
    {
        listView1.BeginUpdate();
        listView1.Items.Clear();
        System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch myStopWatch = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch();
        myStopWatch.Start(); 
        AddItemsToListView(cables);
        myStopWatch.Stop();
        string str;
        str = myStopWatch.Elapsed.Seconds.ToString();
        string s = str;
        listView1.EndUpdate();
    }


    private void AddItemsToListView(List<Cable> cables)
    {
        //Add to an ArrayList first because AddRange is a lot faster
        //than Add when dealing with lots of elements.
        //Also, there is no need to turn off the sorter when adding
        //all the elements at once

        ArrayList listItems = new ArrayList();

        foreach (Cable cable in cables)
        {
            // The if statement can be removed if all items in
            // MyDataClassCollection should be added to the ListView.               
            listItems.Add(CreateListViewItem(GetCableNavigation(cable)));
        }

        // Adds the items to the ListView
        listView1.Items.AddRange(
        (ListViewItem[])listItems.ToArray(typeof(ListViewItem)));
    }

    // Generate a listviewitem by using the myDataItem instance.
    private static ListViewItem CreateListViewItem(Cable cable)
    {
        ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem(
        new string[]
    {
    cable.Id.ToString(),
       cable.Item.ToString(),
       cable.GeneralFormat + cable.TagNo.ToString() + cable.EndString,
       cable.FromBay + cable.FromPanel, 
       cable.ToBay + cable.ToPanel,
       cable.CableProperty.Catalogue.Type,
       cable.CableProperty.Catalogue.CoreSize,
       cable.CableProperty.CableApplication.Application, 
       cable.CableRevision,
       cable.MinRequestCore.ToString(), 
       cable.Route, 
       cable.Distance.ToString(),
       ((CableStatusEnum)cable.Status).ToString(),
       cable.CableProperty.ProjectId.ToString(), 
       cable.CablePropertyId.ToString(),
       cable.TagNo.ToString(), 
       cable.GeneralFormat,
       cable.Length.ToString(), 
       cable.EndString, 
       cable.User.LastName, 
       cable.EditedOn.ToString()                
   });          
        return item;
    }

   private Cable GetCableNavigation(Cable cable)
    {
        CurrentInfo currentInfo = CurrentInfo.RecGetSingle();
        if (cable.CableProperty == null || cable.User == null)
        {
            using (CableServiceClient client = new CableServiceClient())
            {
                SearchElement[] criteria = new SearchElement[] { new SearchElement { Comparison = "=", FieldName = "Id", FieldValue = cable.Id, LogicalOperator = "" } };
                cable = client.GetCables(criteria, null, "CableProperty,CableProperty.Catalogue,CableProperty.CableApplication,User").SingleOrDefault();
                client.Close();
            }
        }
        return cable;
    }
```

i could reduce time of loading to 29 seconds, but it is still too much for 1286 records, how can i reduce the time of loading data?

Thank you

Comment: Post the code for GetCableNavigation

Comment: I would use an generic list (`List<ListViewItem>`) over an `ArrayList`

Comment: Where are getting `List<Cable> cables` from? Maybe there is lazy loading involved and multiple round trips to the database?

Comment: @Ahmed KRAIEM  i don't have problem in retrieving data from database, i have problem in populating the data into the listview

Comment: @nnmmss After seeing your edit, you should try to get all `Cable`s at once from the service call.

Comment: do you need to call `SingleOrDefault`? would not `FirstOrDefault` suffice? `SingleOrDefault` is a little slower.

Comment: @Secret i changed it , and it din't make any changes

Comment: @nnmmss I'd try temporarily removing the service call and seeing if the speed improves dramatically. I think that's the slow spot.

Comment: A performance profiler is your best friend! JetBrains dotTrace and ANTS performance profiler both have trial versions which would show you exactly where the problem is.

Answer (score 2):

I think most of time your code waists in creating service clients and querying data from it. I suggest you to split data loading (you can do it in background thread) and data displaying operations. Consider also re-using single service client instance.

Something like:

```
private void AddItemsToListView(List<Cable> cables)
{
    var items = GetCableNaviagations(cables)
                   .Select(CreateListViewItem)                       
                   .ToArray();

    listView1.Items.AddRange(items);
}

// consider to do data retrieving in background thread
private IEnumerable<Cable> GetCableNaviagations(IEnumerable<Cable> cables)
{
   var arg = "CableProperty,CableProperty.Catalogue,CableProperty.CableApplication,User";

   using (CableServiceClient client = new CableServiceClient())
   {
        foreach(var cable in cables)
        {
           var criteria = new SearchElement[] { 
              new SearchElement { 
                   Comparison = "=", 
                   FieldName = "Id", 
                   FieldValue = cable.Id, 
                   LogicalOperator = ""      
              } };

           yield return client.GetCables(criteria, null, arg).SingleOrDefault();
        }

        client.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: And possibly get all the `Cable`s at once to reduce round trips and connection overhead.

Comment: @Ahmed why do u think it is from retrieving data from db. suppose i have a list with 1286 items in it, and i want to populate listview from that list, i fetch data from database in less than a second

Comment: I think that @Ahmed is speaking of getting all the cable information at once, you seem to get all the cable info from the database (before this code), but then you do 1286 trips to the CableServiceClient. If you could bring all the information from the service client along in the first query it'd likely be much faster.

Comment: @lazyberezovsky I haven't done it before. how can do it in background thread? can you give an example?

Comment: @nnmmss You can use [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221403(v=vs.95).aspx) component for preparing data in background thread. But try this code and let me know if it was fast enough

Answer (score 2):

Assuming this is a `System.Windows.Forms.ListView`, you should take a look at [virtualization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.virtualmode.aspx). Using virtualization will automatically do the lazy loading of the listview items for you, resulting in less memory usage, and better response time.

Comment: Good point on VirtualMode - OP can load cable navigation when it is needed. Depends of course on query speed

Comment: @lazyberezovsky indeed, it depends on query speed, but OP said approx 1200 items take approx 30 seconds, that's 40 items per second or 25 milliseconds per item. That is faster than human perception.

Comment: `1200` items is not too many to consider using `virtualization`, although it's better to use it. BUT the original **cause** making the considerable delay **should be fixed** another way rather than using `virtualization`.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't change so much the time of data retrieving, but could help in the "loading" phase for the listview. Create a Method that return a "ListViewItem[]" and use the Yield return:

```
private void PopulateListViewWithCables(List<Cable> cables)
{
    listView1.BeginUpdate();
    listView1.Items.Clear();
    System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch myStopWatch = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch();
    myStopWatch.Start();         
    foreach (listitem i in AddItemsToListView(cables))
    {
            cables.Add(i);
    }
    AddItemsToListView(cables);
    myStopWatch.Stop();
    string str;
    str = myStopWatch.Elapsed.Seconds.ToString();
    string s = str;
    listView1.EndUpdate();
}


private IEnumerable<ListViewItem> AddItemsToListView(List<Cable> cables)
{
    foreach (Cable cable in cables)
    {        
        yield return(CreateListViewItem(GetCableNavigation(cable)));
    }

}
```

I wrote it without checking if it compile.

Comment: Sorry but i couldn't understand it, can u tell me just a litlle about it

Comment: Yeah my example are based on the Yield Return mechanism.

[link]http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/9k7k7cf0.aspx[/link]

So in a foreach loop you don't have to wait that all the ListItems[] is populated to put it on a ListView, but meanwhile the items are created, like in a separeted thread the every single item is created and returned one by one. So the ListView starts to be populated quickly.